# Simple Stack and Map program stuck

Tags: dictionary, c++11, stack

What is wrong with this simple program and why it is going in hang status on [cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F%20Example%20program%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%20%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aint%20main()%0A%7B%0A%20%20std%3A%3Astring%20name%3B%0A%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20%22What%20is%20your%20name%3F%20%22%3B%0A%20%20getline%20(std%3A%3Acin%2C%20name)%3B%0A%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%3C%3C%20name%20%3C%3C%20%22!%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D)

```
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string expression {")"};    
    stack<char> mystack;
    map<char, char> mymap{ {'(', ')'}, {'[', ']'}, {'{', '}'} };
    set<char> myset{ ')', ']', '}'};

    for(auto &i: expression)
    {
        if(mymap.count(i) == 1)
        {
            mystack.push(i);
        }
        
        else if(myset.count(i) == 1)
        {
            cout << "Received :: " << i << endl;
            
            if(mymap.at(mystack.top()) == i)
            {
                cout << " Popped: " << mystack.top() << endl;
                mystack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Non Balanced" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(mystack.size() != 0)
    {
        cout << "Non Balanced" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the fact that you're attempting to access the top of an empty stack, which leads to undefined behavior. Specifically, when the input expression starts with a closing parenthesis (e.g., `expression = ")"`), the program enters a state where it continuously attempts to pop from an empty stack.

To fix this, you should add a check to ensure that the stack is not empty before using `mystack.top()`.

```
for(auto &i: expression)
{
    if(mymap.count(i) == 1)
    {
        mystack.push(i);
    }
    
    else if(myset.count(i) == 1)
    {
        cout << "Received :: " << i << endl;
        
        if(!mystack.empty() && mymap.at(mystack.top()) == i)
        {
            cout << " Popped: " << mystack.top() << endl;
            mystack.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Non Balanced" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification, your program should work correctly for various cases of balanced and unbalanced parentheses.

Remember to test your program with a variety of input expressions to ensure it handles all cases correctly.

Comment: why mystack.top() in if() is going into continuous state but not if i call it outside if()?

Comment: When you call `mystack.top()` without checking if the stack is empty, it can lead to undefined behavior. This is because there's no valid top element in an empty stack. Calling it outside the `if()` doesn't cause an issue because it's not part of a condition. Always check if the stack is not empty before accessing its top element to avoid potential problems.